# generate string for SQL query

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

I have this string

D_Y_A7,D_Z_A7,D_Z_PRE_A7,D_PC_Z_A7,
D_Y_A8,D_Z_A8,D_Z_PRE_A8,D_PC_Z_A8,
D_Y_A9,D_Z_A9,D_Z_PRE_A9,D_PC_Z_A9

and i try to generate like this

```
ed.Y_A7, ed.Z_A7, pre.Z_A7, pr(pre.Z_A7,ed.Z_A7),ed.Y_A8, ed.Z_A8, pre.Z_A8, pr(pre.Z_A8,ed.Z_A8), ed.Y_A9, ed.Z_A9, pre.Z_A9, pr(pre.Z_A9,ed.Z_A9)
```

I try with this query

```
    select REGEXP_REPLACE (
                replace (
                          replace ('D_Y_A7,D_Z_A7,D_Z_PRE_A7,D_PC_Z_A7,D_Y_A8,D_Z_A8,D_Z_PRE_A8,D_PC_Z_A8,D_Y_A9,D_Z_A9,D_Z_PRE_A9,D_PC_Z_A9', 'D_' , 'ed.') ,
                'ed.Z_PRE' , 'pre.Z') ,
  '(\ed.PC_*)', 'pr(pre.\2' ) from dual
```

Now i have this output

```
"ed.Y_A7,ed.Z_A7,pre.Z_A7,pr(pre.Z_A7,ed.Y_A8,ed.Z_A8,pre.Z_A8,pr(pre.Z_A8,ed.Y_A9,ed.Z_A9,pre.Z_A9,pr(pre.Z_A9"
```

please help me to convert "**pr(pre.Z_A7"** to "**pr(pre.Z_A7,ed.Z_A7)**"

Thank you

Comment: why not `replace(str, 'pr(pre.Z_A7', 'pr(pre.Z_A7,ed.Z_A7)')`?

Comment: Number are dynamic. I can not use A7, that's why i am trying with REGEXP_REPLACE .